# How to get all errors after calling to mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using this code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$sql = file_get_contents("my_sql_file.sql");
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql);

if (!$result)
  report_error(); //my function

while ($mysqli->more_results()) {
  $result = $mysqli->next_result();
  if (!$result)
    report_error();
}
```

However the 'while' loop in the code above turned out to be an infinite loop. Anything wrong?

Comment: I don't work in mysqli but I think this would make senese ` if($mysqli->more_results())
 while ($result = $mysqli->next_result()) {
  if (!$result)
    report_error();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code doesn't really make sense. The proper way to handle multiqueries is the following (see [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php))

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        // store first result set 
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                // do something with the row
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        else { error_report(); }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
else { error_report(); }
```

Comment: i didn't mean to get the query results, only wanted to get all the errors. does it seem that the function mysqli_more_results useless?

Comment: as Jon said in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867048/when-does-mysqli-multi-query-stop-execution if errors may occur, there will be only one reported and mysqli_multi_query stops execution.

Comment: the other answer has some more info to answer this question

Comment: @Anonymous, `error_report()` only needs to be called once.  Add ` && $mysqli->more_results()` to the while condition and append `if($mysqli->error){error_report();}` to the above code then any error will break the if-condition or the while-condition, and will be caught by the if error statement.

Answer (score 3):

The code provided in the question reaches to an infitie loop because "If your second or late query returns no result or even if your query is not a valid SQL query, more_results(); returns true in any case.", see this note on php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#104076

And further more, mysqli_more_results always returns true in the code because the results are not discarded, must call mysqli_store_results to discard result after each call to mysqli_next_result. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#91677

There is no official way to catch all errors when executing MySQL text (multi-commands separated by semicolons) by mysqli_multi_query. The function mysqli_multi_query will stop execution when it faces a bad SQL command, so it is only possible to catch the first error (no matter where the error occurs, in the first SQL command or any other SQL command in the SQL text).

Related to Jon's answer to this question: [When does mysqli_multi_query stop execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867048/when-does-mysqli-multi-query-stop-execution)

And as noted in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#106126 The first error can be catched by scanning mysqli_next_result coz: $mysqli->next_result() will return false if it runs out of statements OR if the next statement has an error.

Finally the answer is that results must be discarded after calling to mysqli_next_result using mysqli_store_result:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$sql = file_get_contents("my_sql_file.sql");
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql);

if (!$result)
  report_error(); //my function

while ($mysqli->more_results()) {
  $result = $mysqli->next_result();

  //important to make mysqli_more_results false:
  $discard = $mysqli->store_result(); 

  if (!$result)
    report_error();
}
```