# When does mysqli_multi_query stop execution?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

Suggested that we have this SQL text with 3 MySQL commands:

```
show tables;

some nonesense command which makes error;

show tables;
```

The first and third SQL are valid, the second isn't. So, when passing this SQL text to mysqli_multi_query, does MySQL stop execution at the second command (error one) or it tries to  go on until the last command? Coz it is dangerous if those commands after the error one relies on the error one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if one query fails the rest will not be executed. See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#106126) over at the documentation for `mysqli_multi_query`, which makes this clear and also showcases one way to check for errors.

Comment: tks jon, just coz it isn't documented officially.